# Pages appear to be cached, showing old data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have two pages (say page1 and page2) in my app. Page1 has two lists - a list of completed tasks and a list of incomplete tasks. Page2 shows the task selected and gives an option to mark the status as complete or incomplete. When you mark as complete, it creates a new page1 and navigates to that - and this new page1 should now show that task in the 'complete' list. Unfortunately it doesn't, it's still in the 'incomplete list'. If I close the app and open it again, the task will be in the 'complete' list like it should be. It's as if a cached page is displaying, but a new one is being created on navigation. Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you navigating to page 1? you should just do `NavigationService.GoBack()`. Also, make sure your view models properly implement INotifyPropertyChanged ... that way, when you change the property, any view elements that are watching it will automatically update themselves through the binding mechanism.

Comment: I'm not using NavigationService.GoBack() because page2 can be accessed from other pages, not just page1, but I always want it to navigate back to page1 from page2 when that button is clicked. Will look at the INotifyPropertyChanged, haven't dealt with that before. Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest that you read this post which gives you information on mitigating issues like this that arise when making navigation loops: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx